# Cannot reach pod after deploying prometheus

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, kind

I'm a newbie on K8s, please forgive me if this is a straightforward question.

### TL;DR

I deployed a classic server-client architecture using a k8s service to reach server by using service's FQDN.

When I apply only the below yaml, server is reachable from client (i.e.: `wget -O- my-service` returns Apache hello page).
When I apply also kube-prometheus as in [their quickstart](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/kube-prometheus#quickstart) (`kubectl apply --server-side -f manifests/setup -f manifests`) I can no more reach server (`wget` returns `Connection Refused`).

**I'm using [kind](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user/quick-start/) on Windows 10**

### The problem

I need to deploy Prometheus on kubernetes to scale pods based on some custom metrics. My pods follows the classic server-client architecture; the below yaml is something similar to what I have actually deployed on k8s.

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: apache
  labels:
    app: apache
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: apache
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: apache
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: apache
        image: httpd:2.4-alpine
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: alpine
  labels:
    app: alpine
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: alpine
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: alpine
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: alpine
        image: alpine:3.15
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
  labels:
    service: my-service
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    protocol: TCP
    name: server-tcp
  selector:
    app: apache
```

If I deploy this yaml **before** following [kube-prometheus quickstart](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/kube-prometheus/tree/v0.10.0#quickstart), `apache` is reachable from `alpine`;
i.e. (from alpine):

```sh
$ wget -q -O- my-service
<html><body><h1>It works!</h1></body></html>
```

If I deploy it **after** deploying kube-prometheus, `apache` is no more reachable from `alpine`;
i.e. (from alpine):

```sh
$ wget -q -O- my-service
Connecting to my-service
wget: can't connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

I don't know whether this is a bug from kube-prometheus or I'm doing something wrong. I tried to google a lot but I couldn't find any working solution for this problem.
I tried with `iptables --policy FORWARD ALLOW` on `apache` pod, but it didn't work (no permission even if command was issued as root).

Any help is appreciated.

**I'm using [kind](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user/quick-start/) on Windows 10**

#### Update

`alpine` pod has no logs.
Here are the logs for `apache` pod (with IPs and PID removed)

```
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using pod_internal_ip. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Tue Feb 01 12:30:58.430151 2022] [mpm_event:notice] AH00489: Apache/2.4.52 (Unix) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Feb 01 12:30:58.430280 2022] [core:notice] AH00094: Command line: 'httpd -D FOREGROUND'
```

Comment: There are many manifest files from prometheus to check in order to help you. It would help if you see and post the logs of the pods created using `kubectl logs`

Comment: `alpine` has no logs while `apache` shows normal startup logs. See the update for details

Comment: after you deploy `prometheus`, can you exec into `apache` and do a `curl http://localhost` just to make sure the server is still listening?

Comment: Yes, it's responding with hello page, i.e.: `wget -q -O- localhost` from inside `apache` container outputs `<html><body><h1>It works!</h1></body></html>`